# Selecting a part of a string

Tags: php, pattern-matching

I have a string stored in variable say

```
$input = 999 success: id:10.123/AVC13231 | ark:/asf4523/2425fsaf
```

I want to select only a part of a string "10.123/AVC13231"

say i want to achieve this:

```
$output = 10.123/XXXXXXXX ;
```

and no other part $input should be selected even the id: part

The value 10.123 is constant and the value AVC13231 changes dynamically.

How can i achieve the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution.

```
$input = "999 success: id:10.123/AVC13231 | ark:/asf4523/2425fsaf";
$pos1 = strpos($input, 'id:')+3;    // Remove 'id:'
$pos2 = strpos($input, '|')-1;      // Remove space before pipe
$output = substr($input, $pos1, ($pos2 - $pos1));
```

Comment: a bit faster than me, but i got it on one line :)

Answer (score 3):

And the mandatory regex solution:

```
preg_match("/id:([^\s]*)/", $input, $matches);
$output = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
$data = substr($input, $startpos=(strpos($input, "id:")+3), strpos($input, ' ', $startpos)-$startpos);
```

Not tested, but the logic is there, just adapt correctly the algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$input = "999 success: id:10.123/AVC13231 | ark:/asf4523/2425fsaf";

$first_split=explode(" |",$input);
$input_split1=$first_split[0];
$second_split=explode("10.123",$input_split1);
$input_split2=$second_split[1];
$output="10.123".$input_split2;

echo $output;
```

Comment: This is PHP, what is your `$input_split1.explode(...);` ? The variable is a string (primitive type), not an object.

Comment: sorry for the mistake..Check that out...While answering I was in hurry