# Select part of a string between two brackets

Tags: php

How select part of string between two brackets.

An example select `kanych` from `(kanych) Kurva Ggglo`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting a part of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636319/selecting-a-part-of-a-string)

Comment: Can you please confirm the actual string and actual output expect ? as someone has edited your question so am unsure of the actual starting string !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
/ ... /     begin and end  
\( ... \)   the brackets of your choice (round brackets have to be escaped)  
( ... )     remember the content  
[^\)]*      the content, every character except the bracket
```

php:

```
$sTest = "(kanych) Kurva Ggglo";
preg_match("/\(([^\)]*)\)/", $sTest, $aMatches);
$sResult = $aMatches[1];
```

Also see [this example](http://ideone.com/aoUHS).

P.s.: with `preg_match_all(...)` you can get all bracket contents from a string.

Comment: You're welcome. It would be fair, if you could accept the correct answers of your questions.

Answer (score 3):

```
$str = "lolo (kanya) momomo";   
$openstrpos  = strpos($str,"(" );
$closestrpos = strpos($str,")");
$finalstr = substr($str, $openstrpos+1, $closestrpos-$openstrpos-1);
```

One of the way you can get required output